# Ionic 2/3 - appending custom component(s) on runtime click event

Tags: angular, ionic3

This question is between Ionic 2 and Angular 4.
I have a requirement which is more like a **page builder** of predefined ionic 2 custom components on click or any event trigger.

How do I go about this? All my research isn't getting me there.

Thanks

Comment: Read [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e) and maybe ask some follow-up specific questions

Answer (score 1):

**WORKED LIKE CHARM**

I finally found it. I needed to use the componentFactoryResolver. 
Thanks to https://blog.thecodecampus.de/angular-2-dynamically-render-components/

The above link kickstarted my goal. The key difference in my case was that my PAGE is lazyloaded and all my components are lazyloaded. So therefore, **page.module.ts** needed to have the **childcomponent.module.ts** added at **imports: []** and the **childcomponent.ts** needs to be added at the **entryComponent: []**. The rest is grabbing and dumping. See below:

**PAGE ngMODULE**

```
import { ChildComponent } from './../../../components/child/child';
import { ChildComponentModule } from '../../../components/child/child.module';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LessonBuilderPage } from './lesson-builder'; //hosting page

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LessonBuilderPage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(LessonBuilderPage),
    ChildComponentModule
  ],
  exports: [
    LessonBuilderPage
  ],
  entryComponents:[
    ChildComponent 
  ]
})
export class LessonBuilderPageModule {}
```

**PAGE.ts**

```
import { ChildComponent } from './../../../components/child/child';
import { Component,ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, ComponentFactoryResolver } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-lesson-builder',
  templateUrl: 'lesson-builder.html',
})
export class LessonBuilderPage {
  @ViewChild('menucontainer', {read: ViewContainerRef}) menucontainer: ViewContainerRef;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {

  }
  addcomponent(){
    const childComponent_var = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(childComponent);    
    this.menucontainer.createComponent(childComponent_var);

  }



  ionViewDidLoad() {
  }

}
```

**PAGE.html**

```
<ion-content #pagecontent padding>
    <div #menucontainer>

    </div>
    <button (click)="addcomponent()" ion-button full>Add component</button>
</ion-content>
```